# Flash Senocular Transform Tool - controls are not showing on the tool

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, transform, scaletransform

I am having trouble with the controls showing up for my transform tool. When I click my image I get the bounding box (to scale or rotate the image), but when I hover over the corner I do not get the cursor to transform it.

[image: image with bounding box]

I am using these files:

[TransformTool.as](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/TransformTool.as)

[TransformToolControl.as](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/TransformToolControl.as)

[TransformToolCursor.as](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/TransformToolCursor.as)

This is my code to call the transform tool:

```
var tool:TransformTool = new TransformTool();
    addChild(tool);
```

And this later on to make the tool show up when the image is clicked and make the tool disappear when the stage is clicked:

```
tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);

function select(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tool.target = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, deselect);
    }

function deselect(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tool.target = null;
        tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
    }
```

My image selection for the bounding box to appear and disappear work perfectly. All my code works as expected.... except the actual controls on the bounding box. Please help!

**Edit**

The concept is the user can click an image from a menu and drag a new instance of that image to the stage. Then the user can click the new instance and should be able to rotate or scale it. Then they can click off the image to make the bounding box disappear.  (They can add as many images to the stage that they want).

Here is some code that shows the basic click, create new instance, and drag process I have implemented.

```
        //sb1 is the menu area that contains a group of images
        //hill is one of the images the user can add to the stage
        sb1.hill.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, createCopy);
            var i:int=0;
            var tmpImage:Sprite; //to store which image is being dragged currently

        function createCopy(e:MouseEvent):void {
            tmpImage = new Hill_mc();
            tmpImage.name = "hillChild"+(i++); //increment every copy
            container.addChild(tmpImage);
            tmpImage.x = mouseX-470;
            tmpImage.y = mouseY-270;
            tmpImage.startDrag();
            tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown); //add the mouse down to this new object
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp); //since the mouse is currently down, we need to listen for mouse up to tell the current copy to stop dragging
        }

        //this will be called when click a copy
        function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
            tmpImage = Sprite(e.currentTarget); //get a reference to the one that was clicked, so we know which object to stop dragging on the global mouse up.
            container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp); //listen for the mouse up
            tmpImage.startDrag();
        }
        function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
            container.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp);
            if (tmpImage.hitTestObject(thesubmenu1)) {
                container.removeChild(tmpImage);
            }
            else {
                tmpImage.stopDrag();
            }
            tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
        }
        function select(e:MouseEvent):void {
            tool.target = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
            tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, deselect);
        }

        function deselect(e:MouseEvent):void {
            tool.target = null;
            tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
        }
```

**EDIT**

I found this code and placed it in my TransformTool.as. I feel like it's so close and that there must be something called incorrectly because I get an error for a null object reference:

```
    public function select(event:Event):void {
        // the selected object will either be the
        // event target or current target. The current
        // target is checked first followed by target.
        // The parent of the target must match the
        // parent of the tool to be selected this way.

        if (event.currentTarget != this 
        && event.currentTarget.parent == parent){

            setTarget(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject, event);

        }else if (event.target != this 
        && event.target.parent == parent){

            setTarget(event.target as DisplayObject, event);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper selection handler for deselecting target objects. Set this
     * handler as the listener for an event that would cause the
     * deselection of a target object.
     * It is not required that you use this event handler. It is only a 
     * helper function that can optionally be used to help ease 
     * development.
     */
    public function deselect(event:Event):void {
        if (_target != null && event.eventPhase == EventPhase.AT_TARGET){
            setTarget(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have added a mousevent listener on stage. So if you click on the image or any other thing in the stage, the deselect funciton will kick in. try to add the MOUSE_DOWN listener on tmpImage object itself.

Comment: I want that, though. Currently, the user clicks the image and gets the bounding box. Then if they are done rotating/scaling it (if I can get the controls to appear and work), they can click anywhere else to deselect the image. 

When I put the deselect on tmpImage, it goes in a loop and just stays selected. That is not the function I want. I want the user to be able to click the image, see the bounding box, make the edits they want and click off the image when they are done. But the controls on that bounding box do not appear. :(

Comment: if you can check the code at 818 at TransformTool.as you will find they already added the eventlisteners to stage. May be that's tha cause. I think use the function to deslect the image inside tranformtool.as

Answer (score 1):

You give too little information to determine what exactly is wrong.
However, there is a very good sample code that does exactly what you want here :

http://www.senocular.com/demo/TransformToolAS3/TransformTool.html
(Click on the link at the bottom of the image.)

I am sure that you are going to make it with this.

EDIT :

Try to use the built-in handlers. I would do something like this :

Instead of this :

```
tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);

function select(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tool.target = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, deselect);
    }

function deselect(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tool.target = null;
        tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
    }
```

Do this :

```
tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.select);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tool.deselect);
```

EDIT :

If you do not have the handlers, I am not sure :) but I would recommand removing event listeners in each method as they might be interfering with each other.

```
tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);

function select(e:MouseEvent):void {
        tmpImage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
        tool.target = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, deselect);
    }

function deselect(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, deselect);
        tool.target = null;
        tmpImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, select);
    }
```

Comment: I have added some more code to my question. The link you provided is the first instance of the tool I found. I used those files first, but then went the route with the basic sources and got much further. I am soooo close, haha!

Comment: I have tried this before but I get an error: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property select not found on com.senocular.display.transform.TransformTool and there is no default value.
 at Seal()

I don't see the select and deselect call in the TransformTool.as. Do I just add what I have above to that .as file instead?